# Tikzpicture: How to make an edge not cross a node in a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,%
main node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=20pt, inner sep =1pt},node   distance=0.5cm]
% the vertices
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,minimum size=3pt] [label=left:Source] (source)   at (0,-0.9) {};
  \node[main node] (three) at (1.5,0) {E1};
 \node[main node] [above=of three] (a) {D8};
 \node[main node] [above=of a] (two) {D1};
 \node[main node] [below=of three] (four) {N1};
 \node[main node] [below=of four, label=center:RD] (fourteen) {\phantom{0}};
\node[main node] [below=of fourteen] (b) {DO};
\node[main node] [right=of three] (six) {E1};
\node[main node] [above=of six] (five) {D8};
 \node[main node] [above=of five] (g) {D1};
\node[main node] [below=of six] (seven) {N1};
\node[main node][right=of six] (eight) {E1};
 \node[main node] [below=of seven] (fifthteen) {RD};
  \node[main node] [below=of fifthteen] (d) {DO};
  \node[main node] [above=of eight] (nine) {D8};
   \node[main node] [above=of nine] (c) {D1};
   \node[main node] [below=of eight] (ten) {N1};
   \node[main node] [below=of ten] (sixteen) {RD};
 \node[main node] [below=of sixteen] (e) {DO};
\node[main node] [right=of nine] (seventeen) {D8};
  \node[main node] [above=of seventeen] (c) {D1};
\node[main node] [below=of seventeen] (elleven) {E1};
\node[main node] [below=of elleven] (twelwe) {N1};
\node[main node] [below=of twelwe] (thirteen) {RD};
 \node[main node] [below=of thirteen] (f) {DO};
 \node[main node] [right=of c] (h) {D1};
   \node[main node] [below=of h] (i) {D8};
  \node[main node] [below=of i] (j) {E1};
\node[main node] [below=of j] (k) {N1};
 \node[main node] [below=of k] (l) {RD};
 \node[main node] [below=of l] (m) {DO};
      \node[main node] [right=of h] (n) {D1};
   \node[main node] [below=of n] (o) {D8};
  \node[main node] [below=of o] (p) {E1};
\node[main node] [below=of p] (q) {N1};
\node[main node] [below=of q] (r) {RD};
 \node[main node] [below=of r] (s) {DO};
 \node[main node] [right=of n] (t) {D1};
   \node[main node] [below=of t] (u) {D8};
  \node[main node] [below=of u] (v) {E1};
\node[main node] [below=of v] (w) {N1};
\node[main node] [below=of w] (x) {RD};
 \node[main node] [below=of x] (y) {DO};
 % the edges
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
 (four) edge [dashed] node {} (seven)
       edge node {} (fifthteen)
           edge [dashed] node {} (d)
(fifthteen) edge [dashed] node {} (sixteen)
                edge [dashed] node {} (ten)
                edge node {} (e)
(e) edge [dashed] node {} (elleven)
        edge [dashed] node {} (seventeen)
        edge [dashed] node {} (twelwe)
        edge node {} (c)
        edge [dashed] node {} (thirteen)
        edge [dashed] node {} (f)
(source) edge [dashed] node {} (two)
            edge [dashed] node {} (three)
            edge node {} (four)
            edge [dashed] node {} (fourteen)
            edge [dashed] node {} (a)
            edge [dashed] node {} (b)
    (c) edge [dashed] node {} (h)
        edge [dashed] node {} (i)
        edge node {} (j)
        edge [dashed] node {} (k)
        edge [dashed] node {} (l)
        edge [dashed] node {} (m)
    (j) edge [dashed] node {} (n)
        edge [dashed] node {} (s)
        edge node {} (o)
        edge [dashed] node {} (p)
        edge [dashed] node {} (q)
        edge [dashed] node {} (r)       
    (o) edge node {} (x)
;
\draw [|-|] (0.6,-6.5) -- (2.3,-6.5);
\draw [-|] (2.3,-6.5) -- (4.0,-6.5);
\draw [-|] (4.0,-6.5) -- (5.7,-6.5);
\draw [-] (5.7,-6.5) -- (7.4,-6.5);
\draw [|-|] (7.4,-6.5) -- (9.1,-6.5);
\node [below] at (1.4,-6.5) {Day 1};
\node [below] at (3.1,-6.5) {Day 2};
\node [below] at (4.8,-6.5) {Day 3};
\node [below] at (6.5,-6.5) {Day 4};
\node [below] at (8.2,-6.5) {Day 5};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

The code above gives the following figure. However I would like that the edges are not crossing over the nodes. For example the edge from DO cross over both RD and D1. How do I move the edges such that they do not cross over any of the nodes?

[image]

Comment: Please make your example into a complete minimum WORKING example.

Comment: `\tikzset{to path={(\tikztostart)..controls+(1,0)and($(\tikztotarget)-(1.5,0)$)..(\tikztotarget)}}`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following to your code

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    to path={
        \pgfextra{
            \tikz@scan@one@point\relax(\tikztostart)
            \pgfmathsetmacro\start@x{\pgf@x}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\start@y{\pgf@y}
            \tikz@scan@one@point\relax(\tikztotarget)
            \pgfmathsetmacro\target@x{\pgf@x}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\target@y{\pgf@y}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\middle@x{(\start@x+\target@x)/2}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\middle@ya{(4*\start@y+\target@y)/5}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\middle@yb{(\start@y+4*\target@y)/5}
        }
        ..controls(\middle@x pt,\middle@ya pt)and(\middle@x pt,\middle@yb pt)..(\tikztotarget)
    }
}
```

[image]

## idea

to draw a curve that avoids other nodes, we need two auxiliary points: *A* and *B*. It is of course your freedom to decide where should *A* and *B* be.

In my code, the x-coordinate of them is the average. The y-coordinates are 1:5 and 4:5 of the difference of the two ends. This is the reason you why can see `/2` and `4*` and `/5`.

[image]